# Android - Recyclerview not starting from the top

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I've already seen similar problem and tried all kind of solutions, this is what I ended up with:

```
    layoutManagerMemes = LinearLayoutManager(
        this@MainActivity,
        LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
        false
    )

    recyclerViewMemes.setHasFixedSize(false)
    recyclerViewMemes.adapter = adapterMemes
    recyclerViewMemes.layoutManager = layoutManagerMemes

    recyclerViewMemes.scrollToPosition(0)
```

The XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    
    
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    
    
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewMemes"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
            </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Could the issue be the images that are loaded after RecyclerView is set?

Ignore this: Stackoverflow demands some more text, Enter each item on a new line, choose the amount of groups unders settings, and click the button to generate your randomized list. Don't like the first team? Just click again until you do

Comment: the problem Seems to be in your Item layout . See if your Items are not taking the whole height of `RecyclerView` .

Comment: @ADM nope they aren't and the height is set to wrap_content

Comment: Try using recyclerViewMemes.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0); instead of recyclerViewMemes.scrollToPosition(0)

Comment: I got unresolved reference for scrollToPositionWithOffset so I tried (recyclerViewMemes.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0) but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the only way to avoid it is to know the image dimensions and set them before the image is loaded by calculating the ratio